# Can't call python script with "python" command

Tags: python

I normally program in Java, but started learning Python for a course I'm taking.

I couldn't really start the first exercise because the command

```
python count_freqs.py gene.train > gene.counts
```

didn't work, I keep getting "`incorrect syntax`" messages. I tried solving this looking at dozens of forums but nothing works, and I'm going crazy.

```
import count_freqs
```

ran without errors, but I can't do anything with it. When I try running something involving the file `gene.train` I get "`gene is not defined`".

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell without the actual code you are trying to run. Please provide.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to execute the python script within the python interactive shell.  You need to run this within your normal shell (bash, csh, windows command prompt, etc...)

Comment: how are you handling parsing arguments? does it have a `if __name__ == '__main__':` line ? need moar code

Comment: Thanks SethMMorton, you're right.
Sorry for the rookie mistake, I guess this was so obvious to most that no one bothered to explain it in the description of the exercise or in other forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Windows you can type **echo %%PATH%%**  at the command prompt. It will give you at list of all the directories the shell search for programs to run. By default Python 3.3 will be installed on *C:\Python33*.

Answer (score 1):

type `which python` at the command prompt to see if the python executable is in your path. If not it either isn't installed or you need to amend your path to include it.